# Reduce HTTP Requests method for js and css

Tags: css, javascript, http, connections

Is these way can Reduce HTTP Requests?

multiple javascript files with `&` symbol

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?2.5.2/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js
&http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

multiple css files with `@` import

```
<style type="text/css">
@import url(css/style.css);
@import url(css/custom.css);
</style>
```

Comment: Why don't you combine them instead ? By the way, I don't think every browser will understand the `&` where did you see that? (and this lead to a [400 bad request from yahoo](http://hurl.eu/hurls/dec852f3f41104155bcf5dacef1da4e8949404c8/2ee848c04cd35103ad552e8edfe9164d938e1d71))

Comment: Load the JS at the bottom of the page: it won't save you requests, but the page will load a lot faster. As j0k said, combine them. Also minify them if they are not already.

Comment: @j0k, ionFish, the problem is the js file like yui and jquery, It is impossible combine them with some software like `jsmin.exe`, because the licence, and impossible load them in the bottom of the page, many javascript code with relay on them will not work.

Comment: If you can use all your jquery code inside a $(document).ready() function, then you can load the jquery file just before the js/jquery code (as described by ionFish). In some cases that you have some onclick="javascriptcodehere" or similar, and you cannot refactor it to load the script once the document is ready, then you will have to load it on top. Try to use popular CDN for jquery and popular scripts/css: often your visitors will already have the file cached and will not require a full request.

Comment: ok, so @milo5b, any other way to Reduce HTTP Requests? something like jquery  `$.getScript`?

Comment: $.getScript would generate a request. You can go about this problem in two ways, or a mix of the two: 1) try to use popular CDN, so a lot of people would already have cached the file you are about to request (works only for popular stuff i.e. jquery, jquery-ui stuff, popular plugins, etc) 2) try to merge all your scripts into one file, to minimise number of requests. This merged file wouldn't be cached by users that never visited your site though (you could merge jquery.js + plugins + your own code, but i'd rather serve jquery from a popular CDN so chances are that that file is cached) cont'd

Comment: I know this question would be about CSS and JS scripts, but another popular way to reduce number of requests is using sprites for images, instead of lots of small images. Don't know if you need this but I thought I just write it here

Comment: @milo5b, in your mind, what is the best size for a background image? If I combine all of my images into one, the size could be more than 70kb, this will make all the page's text has been loaded, but the background image still on its road...

Comment: If you use a non-repeated background image, I would keep it separate from the sprite. You'd end up with 1 background image + all the other smaller image grouped into one sprite, totalling to 2 requests. Also keep in mind if you use different sets of images for different sections of the sites, try to make 1 sprite per section, in order not to load unneeded images. The size of the background image might vary depending on what you want to achieve: if you have a nice landscape as background, probably it cant be too small. If you have a repeated pattern probably you can do with a small repeated img

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2 examples are minified versions served from popular CDN, so many visitors will have them in their cache, and therefore no HTTP request will be required.

If you want to combine them, download the files and then you need to do some kind of combining the files on the server side. If you are using .NET [SquishIt](http://www.codethinked.com/squishit-the-friendly-aspnet-javascript-and-css-squisher) is a popular choice. If you use PHP [minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) is an option.

In regard to the CSS files, the above two options support those as well.